# SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1: Column name not specified at position 1

Tags: amazon-athena

I am trying to return the below query into a table but I get this error

`SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:1: Column name not specified at position 1`.

But whenever I just select it like

```
SELECT replace(Pharma.Parent_Company, '"', '')
FROM Pharma
```

It doesnt have error

```
CREATE TABLE PHARMA_NEW AS SELECT replace(Pharma.Parent_Company, '"', '')
FROM Pharma
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, you haven't specified a name for the column, only the expression used to create it. In some contexts, that's OK and you'll just get a result column with no name or a generated name, but in this context Athena wants you to choose the name yourself.

So change `replace(Pharma.Parent_Company, '"', '')` to `replace(Pharma.Parent_Company, '"', '') AS whatever_column_name_you_want`.